# What is defined by part by weight in the definition of equivalent weight?

Tags: physical-chemistry, terminology

According to my book, equivalent weight is defined as the ‘number of parts by weight’ of an element that interacts with 1.008 parts by weight of hydrogen. It is dimensionless while gram equivalent weight has gram as units. But in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_weight, equivalent weight and gram equivalent weight are same. I’ve two questions: Which one is correct, my book or Wikipedia? And what is ‘number of parts by weight’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "parts by weight" is how you would specify in a recipe the relative proportions of the ingredients. So if the recipe called for one part by weight of flour and two parts by weight of sugar, you could use 1 ounce of flour and two ounces of sugar (to make a small batch) or 1/2 pound of flour and 1 pound of sugar to make a large batch.

So the "recipe" for water calls for exactly 1.008 parts by weight of hydrogen and 8.000 parts by weight of oxygen. If you use too much of either ingredient, there will be an excess of it after the reaction is run.

"Parts by volume" would apply if you were combining liquids and measuring them by volume rather than by weight.